# Iterate and Map two lists in java 8

Tags: java

I have 2 lists:

1. List1: Object1 (name1, id1)
2. List2: Object2(name2, id2)

Given the size of list1 is the same as list2

I want to iterate ove the list2 and if the name2 of list2 is not null than update the name1 of list1.

here is the code using old java:

```
  for(Object1 obj1:list1) {
    for(Object2 obj2:list2) {
      if(obj1.getId1.equals(obj2.getId2)) {
        obj1.setName1(obj2.getName2);
      }
   }
}
```

Which is the best way to implement this with java.util.stream?

Comment: Currently, your code has quadratic complexity. Do you actually want to check all combinations of elements, or only elements at the same index of their respective list?

Comment: Does `id` mean a unique identifier for your objects? In that case a _map_ with the id as a key is more appropriate than a _list_. It would also reduce time complexity to O(n) (in case of a `HashMap`) instead of O(n^2).

Comment: Yes id is a unique identifier for object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just to be clear, I think your code is intended to do the following: update the name of each item in `list1` to be the name of any item in `list2` that has the same ID. There doesn't seem to be anything checking if the names of items in `list1` are null.

If that's correct, then:

```
list2.forEach(obj2 -> list1.stream()
     .filter(obj1 -> obj1.getId().equals(obj2.getId()))
     .forEach(obj1 -> obj1.setName(obj2.getName()));
```

If you want to check if name is null, then add a new filter before setting the name:

```
    .filter(Objects::isNull)
```

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in the comments. If the `id` is a uniqe identifier for your objects, then a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is more appropriate than a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

So you better work on such a map (assuming id is an integer):

```
Map<Integer, Object1> obj1map;
```

You could create that map from your first list with

```
obj1map = list1.stream().collect(toMap(Object1::getId, Function.identity()));
```

Now you can stream over your second list and update the map accordingly:

```
list2
    .stream()
    .filter(o -> o.getName() != null) // remove null names
    .filter(o -> obj1map.containsKey(o.getId())) // just to make sure
    .forEach(o -> obj1map.get(o.getId()).setName(o.getName()));
```

Answer (score -2):

The idea of a stream is that it does *not* have context. Knowing where you are in the first stream is context which you would need to find the corresponding item in the second stream.

Use a normal `for` loop with an index `i` instead.

```
for (int i=0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
  Object2 item2 = list2.get(i);
  if (list2.get(i).name != null) {
    list1.get(i).name = item.name;
  }
}
```