# generate the Map from Lists using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two List objects from which i want to create the **Map** object using java8.

```
List<Person> personList =..;  //pid,personName,personAge;
List<Address> addressList =..;//pid,location,homeAddress;
 
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to iterate both the list and generate the map by storing pid from personList and location from addressList as key and value pairs using streams.

```
personList.stream().filter(..)//how to iterate the second List?
```

Below is the sample map object it should look

```
  map.put(pid,location);
```

Note: Both personList and addressList are not of same size.

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to put in the Map

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the hash map looks with some `Person`, `Address` objects for reference?

Comment: The `pid`'s are the same ID for the address or the person?

Comment: Yes, address and person has the same pids for reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408435/iterate-and-map-two-lists-in-java-8

Comment: Can you demonstrate the desired behavior using a traditional loop instead of streams?

Comment: You never said if the `personList` and the `addressList` were in alignment.  Would you expect the solution to work if both lists were shuffled?

Answer (score 4):

Stream API does *not* iterate on collections; it rather creates a stream from the source, and you can*not* source one stream from two different resources.

You can use a circumventing approach, and this will do what you're looking for:

```java
List<Person> personList = ...;  //pid, personName, personAge;
List<Address> addressList = ...;//pid, location, homeAddress;

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

//get the size of smaller list, as lists are of different sizes.
int size = Math.min(personList.size(), addressList.size());

IntStream.range(0, size)
        .mapToObj(e -> new SimpleEntry<>(personList.get(e).getPid(), addressList.get(e).getLocation()))
        .forEach(e -> map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

Notes:

1. Make sure you provide appropriate getters in `Person` and `Address`;
2. `import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;`

Comment: ForEach can be removed: `HashMap<String, String> map = IntStream.range(0, size)
        .mapToObj(e -> new SimpleEntry<>(personList.get(e).getPid(), addressList.get(e).getLocation()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that two steps are needed here:

1. Build a map `<pid, location>` on the basis of `addressList`
2. Iterate through `personList` and use `person.pid` to map to the address.

In general case, a person may have several addresses which also may be duplicated, so final map may look as `<pid, Set<location>>`.

```java
// 1. map pid to set of addresses
Map<String, Set<String>> addresses = addressList
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Address::getPid, 
            Collectors.mapping(Address::getLocation, Collectors.toSet())
        ));

// 2. map person ids to addresses
Map<String, Set<String>> personAddresses = personList
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Person::getPid,
            person -> addresses.get(person.getPid()), // Set<location>
            (addr1, addr2) -> addr1 // resolve possible conflicts
        ));
```

If it is guaranteed that the pid/addresses pairs are unique and map <pid, location> can be created, the above code may be simplified:

```java
// 1. map pid to single address
Map<String, String> addressMap = addressList
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Address::getPid, 
            Address::getLocation
        ));

// 2. map person ids to addresses
Map<String, String> personAddress = personList
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Person::getPid,
            // single location, provide default value
            person -> addressMap.getOrDefault(person.getPid(), "Unknown address")
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do it as follows:

- first stream the `addressList` to create an `address map` which has the `pid` as the key and the `address` as the value.
- then stream the `personList`, mapping to the id and filtering on the existence of that id in the `address map`.

This has two advantages.

- The contents of `personList` and `addressList` may be in any order.
- Only those ids in `personList` will be used, ignoring any other ids in the `addressList`.  So the lists are not required to be one-to-one or even the same size.

First, I used two records (classes would also work exactly the same way) to house some data.  For this demo, only the pertinent information is included.

```
record Person(String getPid) {
};
record Address(String getPid, String getLocation) {
};
```

Next, I create lists with the test data. Both lists will contain id's not in the other.

```
List<Person> personList = List.of(new Person("id1"),
        new Person("id2"), new Person("id3"), new Person("id6"));
List<Address> addressList =
        List.of(new Address("id3", "Utah"),
                new Address("id1", "Idaho"),
                new Address("id2", "Virginia"),
                new Address("id5", "New York"));
```

Now create a map of `pid to address`. If two addresses exist for the same id, only the first encountered is used.

```
Map<String, Address> addressMap =
        addressList.stream().collect(Collectors
                .toMap(Address::getPid, address -> address,
                        (ad1,ad2)->ad1));
```

Now create the final map.

- stream the `personList` and pull out the ids
- now filter to ensure the given id is in the `address map`.
- and enter the id and the location for given id in the map

```
Map<String, String> result = personList.stream()
        .map(Person::getPid).filter(addressMap::containsKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(id -> id,
                id -> addressMap.get(id).getLocation));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

For the test data, the following is printed.

```
id2=Virginia
id1=Idaho
id3=Utah
```